# NGINX/PHP cant access files outside root directory

Tags: php, nginx, openbsd

I just installed nginx and php72 on openbsd server to setup an website. I have my website root directory in /var/www/html and want to access some XML files that I store in /var/cache/.
The problem is that that when I try check if file_exists('var/cache/file.xml') it says that it does not exist, but it does!

And after some "debugging" and using of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] says that the path were the root directory is: /www/html but the real path, on server, is /var/www/html so somehow PHP/NGINX can't detect /var which I need since there is were I put my xml file.

Is there something I can enter in php.ini or php-fpm.conf to enable php to read this path?

Hope I did explain that correct for you and that you understand what I mean here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is because of the built-in chroot in nginx for OpenBSD.

https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.4/nginx.8

Try starting nginx with the `-u` flag. It will disable the chroot/jail and allow scripts running in nginx to access other paths on the file system.

From the documentation:

> By default nginx will chroot(2) to the home directory of the user running the daemon, typically “www”, or to the home directory of user in nginx.conf. The -u option disables this behaviour, and returns nginx to the original "unsecure" behaviour.

Comment: Aaaah okay, is there some other way to do this? Some better place for my xmls? Would it be safe to have them in /var/www when my website root is /var/www/html? But maybe still I would not be able to access anything outside /var/www/html? Because when I tried aan relative path like: file_exists('../../cache/file.xml) that did not work either

Comment: So I would set my root in the nginx.conf to /var/www/html/public instead of /var/www/html and serve the xmls from /var/www/cache?

Comment: Btw, thanks alot for the help. I am new to openbsd so did not know about the built-in chroot

Comment: I deleted that comment again :) I didn't see you already had a subdirectory. As long as the root in nginx is set to a sub-folder, e.g. /var/www/html or /var/www/html/public and you chroot is something higher, e.g. /var/www, you are fine. Then the users can only access what's inside that inner folder, but not fetch your xmls by a simple GET request to your site